# How to add dictionary in python from user input for student management system

Tags: python, python-3.x

My program is not working as expected, I thought it should run by number of input which was asked by user. Also, the dictionary is not adding i.e two times , it keeps blank:

```
d={}
i=0
ent_inp=int(input('Enter #1 to add student\nEnter #2 to search student\nEnter #3 to del student\nEnter 4# to exit\n\nEnter your choice= '))
if ent_inp==1:
    howmany=int(input('How many student detail you want to enter: '))
    
    while i<=howmany:

        d['RollNum']=input('Enter the Roll Num: ')
        d['RollNum']={}
        d['RollNum']['Name']=input('Enter the Name: ')
        d['RollNum']['Marks']={}
        d['RollNum']['Marks']['English']=input('Enter the Marks of English: ')
        d['RollNum']['Marks']['Maths']=input('Enter the Marks of Maths: ')
        d['RollNum']['Marks']['Hindi']=input('Enter the Marks of Hindi: ')
        i=i+1
        continue
    print(d)
```

Comment: It is adding two numbers, you just overwrite it on the second iteration - try replacing `d['RollNum']` with `d[i]`

Comment: Do you really want `d['RollNum']={}`? Shouldn't the key at this stage be the roll number which was input in the previous line (rather than the fixed string `'RollNum'`)?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. For debugging help, you need to provide a [mre] including example input, expected output, and actual output. As well, please minimize the code; for example, the choice at `ent_inp` is not relevant to the problem. You can [edit]. Check out [ask] if you want more tips.

Comment: First, it must be a `for` loop since you know the number of iterations ahead of time. Second, you do not need `continue`.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have a better time splitting your logic up to something like this, maybe:

- `input_student` is in charge of requesting the information for a single student; it returns it as a dict.
- `main` contains the rest of the logic, encapsulated as a function to make it harder to accidentally refer to global variables.

  - A `for` loop is better than `while` when you're iterating over a known range.

You could further refactor this to make the various menu entries (once you implement the rest) separate functions.

```
def input_student():
    student = {"Marks": {}}
    student["RollNum"] = input("Enter the Roll Num: ")
    student["Name"] = input("Enter the Name: ")
    student["Marks"]["English"] = input("Enter the Marks of English: ")
    student["Marks"]["Maths"] = input("Enter the Marks of Maths: ")
    student["Marks"]["Hindi"] = input("Enter the Marks of Hindi: ")
    return student


def main():
    students = []

    ent_inp = int(
        input(
            "Enter #1 to add student\n"
            "Enter #2 to search student\n"
            "Enter #3 to del student\n"
            "Enter 4# to exit\n\n"
            "Enter your choice= "
        )
    )
    if ent_inp == 1:
        howmany = int(input("How many student detail you want to enter: "))
        for i in range(howmany):
            students.append(input_student())
        print(students)


main()
```